# Computing the gradients of new state (of the RNN) with respect to model parameters, (including CNN for inputs), in tensorflow; tf.gradient return None

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, gradient

Summary:

I have a 1d CNN that extracts features from the inputs. The CNN is then follows by an RNN. I am looking for a way to back propagate gradients from the `new_state` of the RNN to the CNN parameters. Also, we can consider a conv layer with kernel size `[1, 1, input_num_features, output_num_features]`. The code is below:

import tensorflow as tf

```
mseed = 123
tf.set_random_seed(mseed)
kernel_initializer = tf.glorot_normal_initializer(seed=mseed)

# Graph Hyperparameters
cell_size = 64
num_classes = 2
m_dtype = tf.float32
num_features = 30

inputs_train_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=m_dtype, shape=[None, 75, num_features], name="inputs_train_ph")
inputs_devel_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=m_dtype, shape=[None, 75, num_features], name="inputs_devel_ph")

labels_train_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=m_dtype, shape=[None, 75, num_classes], name="labels_train_ph")
labels_devel_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=m_dtype, shape=[None, 75, num_classes], name="labels_devel_ph")

def return_inputs_train(): return inputs_train_ph
def return_inputs_devel(): return inputs_devel_ph
def return_labels_train(): return labels_train_ph
def return_labels_devel(): return labels_devel_ph

phase_train = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, shape=())
dropout = tf.placeholder(dtype=m_dtype, shape=())
initial_state = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, cell_size], dtype=m_dtype, name="initial_state")

inputs = tf.cond(phase_train, return_inputs_train, return_inputs_devel)
labels = tf.cond(phase_train, return_labels_train, return_labels_devel)

# Graph
def model(inputs):
    used = tf.sign(tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(inputs), 2))

    length = tf.reduce_sum(used, 1)
    length = tf.cast(length, tf.int32)

    with tf.variable_scope('layer_cell'):
        inputs = tf.layers.conv1d(inputs, filters=100, kernel_size=3, padding="same",
                                  kernel_initializer=tf.glorot_normal_initializer(seed=mseed))
        inputs = tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs, training=phase_train, name="bn")
        inputs = tf.nn.relu(inputs)

    with tf.variable_scope('lstm_model'):

        cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(cell_size, kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer)
        cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell, input_keep_prob=1.0 - dropout, state_keep_prob=1.0 - dropout)
        output, new_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, dtype=m_dtype, sequence_length=length,
                                              initial_state=initial_state)

    with tf.variable_scope("output"):
        output = tf.reshape(output, shape=[-1, cell_size])
        output = tf.layers.dense(output, units=num_classes,
                                 kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer)

        output = tf.reshape(output, shape=[5, -1, num_classes])
        used = tf.expand_dims(used, 2)

        output = output * used

    return output, new_state


output, new_state = model(inputs)

grads_new_state_wrt_vars = tf.gradients(new_state, tf.trainable_variables())
for g in grads_new_state_wrt_vars:
    print('**', g)

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
```

Please note that when I printed out the gradients tensors, I got the following:

```
for g in grads_new_state_wrt_vars:
    print('**', g)

** None
** None
** None
** None
** Tensor("gradients/model/lstm_model/rnn/while/gru_cell/MatMul/Enter_grad/b_acc_3:0", shape=(220, 240), dtype=float64)
** Tensor("gradients/model/lstm_model/rnn/while/gru_cell/BiasAdd/Enter_grad/b_acc_3:0", shape=(240,), dtype=float64)
** Tensor("gradients/model/lstm_model/rnn/while/gru_cell/MatMul_1/Enter_grad/b_acc_3:0", shape=(220, 120), dtype=float64)
** Tensor("gradients/model/lstm_model/rnn/while/gru_cell/BiasAdd_1/Enter_grad/b_acc_3:0", shape=(120,), dtype=float64)
** None
** None
```

Finally, the weights in the network are printed below:

```
for v in tf.trainable_variables():
    print(v.name)

model/conv1d/kernel:0
model/conv1d/bias:0
model/bn/gamma:0
model/bn/beta:0
model/lstm_model/rnn/gru_cell/gates/kernel:0
model/lstm_model/rnn/gru_cell/gates/bias:0
model/lstm_model/rnn/gru_cell/candidate/kernel:0
model/lstm_model/rnn/gru_cell/candidate/bias:0
model/output/dense/kernel:0
model/output/dense/bias:0
```

Therefore, how come that the gradients can't be computed wrt to the weights of the first conv, and batch norm, layers in the network?

Please note that I don't have the same problem when replacing `new_state` by `output` in `tf.gradients(new_state, tf.trainable_variables())`

Any help is much appreciated!!

### Edit

I found out that if I change the `None` in the `placeholders` defined above, the problem will be solved. And I got the gradients of the `new_state` wrt to the conv layers. This will work as long as the defined batch size is the same in both train and devel `placeholders`, ex:

```
inputs_train_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=m_dtype, shape=[34, 75, num_features], name="inputs_train_ph")
inputs_devel_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=m_dtype, shape=[34, 75, num_features], name="inputs_devel_ph")

labels_train_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=m_dtype, shape=[34, 75, num_classes], name="labels_train_ph")
labels_devel_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=m_dtype, shape=[34, 75, num_classes], name="labels_devel_ph")
```

Else, I will run into an error again.

Please note that the gradients of the output wrt conv layer won't be affected by the `None` for the batch size in the `placeholders` defined above.

Now I would like to know why I am getting this error had I didn't change the `None` to `batch_size`?

Comment: Please produce a code example that runs standalone

Comment: @tsorn, I have edited the question above with standalone code. I found out that the `None` in the `placeholder` definition caused this error. Replacing the `None` by any read value will solve the problem. BUT WHY? Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: @I.A what is the question? What was the problem in the first place? I can run your standalone code just fine with no errors, with None.

Comment: Tensorflow version 1.12, no problem here, could you specify what is your by issuing `tf.__version__` ?

Comment: Oh, and your shapes do not match during multiplication `output = output * used` when `batch_size` is specified, even when both `devel` and `train` `batch_sizes` match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this constitutes an exact answer to your question, but it might be a good start as it seems your issue does not get much of an attention (and well, tbh, I'm not surprised with this amount of confusion).

Furthermore there are tons of questions (way too much for comments) others might have as well so I will bring them up here (and try to provide an answer to the situation at hand).

#### Tensorflow version: **1.12**

### 1. None gradients

This problem does not exist for either `output` or `new_state` **when `batch_size` is unspecified**.

- Gradients w.r.t. **`new_state`**, e.g. `grads_new_state_wrt_vars = tf.gradients(new_state, tf.trainable_variables())` return:

  ```
  ** Tensor("gradients/layer_cell/conv1d/BiasAdd_grad/BiasAddGrad:0", shape=(100,), dtype=float32)
  ** Tensor("gradients/layer_cell/bn/batchnorm/mul_grad/Mul_1:0", shape=(100,), dtype=float32)
  ** Tensor("gradients/layer_cell/bn/batchnorm/add_1_grad/Reshape_1:0", shape=(100,), dtype=float32)
  ** Tensor("gradients/lstm_model/rnn/while/gru_cell/MatMul/Enter_grad/b_acc_3:0", shape=(164, 128), dtype=float32)
  ** Tensor("gradients/lstm_model/rnn/while/gru_cell/BiasAdd/Enter_grad/b_acc_3:0", shape=(128,), dtype=float32)
  ** Tensor("gradients/lstm_model/rnn/while/gru_cell/MatMul_1/Enter_grad/b_acc_3:0", shape=(164, 64), dtype=float32)
  ** Tensor("gradients/lstm_model/rnn/while/gru_cell/BiasAdd_1/Enter_grad/b_acc_3:0", shape=(64,), dtype=float32)
  ** None
  ** None
  ```

  as expected (as it doesn't pass through the `Dense` part of your network).
- Gradients w.r.t. **`output_state`**, e.g. `grads_new_state_wrt_vars = tf.gradients(output_state, tf.trainable_variables())` return:

  ```
  ** Tensor("gradients/layer_cell/conv1d/BiasAdd_grad/BiasAddGrad:0", shape=(100,), dtype=float32)                                                                                           
  ** Tensor("gradients/layer_cell/bn/batchnorm/mul_grad/Mul_1:0", shape=(100,), dtype=float32)
  ** Tensor("gradients/layer_cell/bn/batchnorm/add_1_grad/Reshape_1:0", shape=(100,), dtype=float32)                                                                                         
  ** Tensor("gradients/lstm_model/rnn/while/gru_cell/MatMul/Enter_grad/b_acc_3:0", shape=(164, 128), dtype=float32)                                                                          
  ** Tensor("gradients/lstm_model/rnn/while/gru_cell/BiasAdd/Enter_grad/b_acc_3:0", shape=(128,), dtype=float32)                                                                             
  ** Tensor("gradients/lstm_model/rnn/while/gru_cell/MatMul_1/Enter_grad/b_acc_3:0", shape=(164, 64), dtype=float32)                                                                         
  ** Tensor("gradients/lstm_model/rnn/while/gru_cell/BiasAdd_1/Enter_grad/b_acc_3:0", shape=(64,), dtype=float32)                                                                            
  ** Tensor("gradients/output/dense/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1:0", shape=(64, 2), dtype=float32)
  ** Tensor("gradients/output/dense/BiasAdd_grad/BiasAddGrad:0", shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
  ```

  Once again, everything is fine.

### 2. Specifying batch_size

When **batch size** is specified as you described, e.g.

```
inputs_train_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=m_dtype, shape=[34, 75, num_features], name="inputs_train_ph")
inputs_devel_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=m_dtype, shape=[34, 75, num_features], name="inputs_devel_ph")
```

your network **DOES NOT** work at all and it's nothing strange as your shapes do not match in the output namespace.

Furthermore, `labels_devel_ph` and `labels_train_ph` does not matter for the code in question, why put them here, they just clutter the question even further. Please see [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), there is a lot of parts totally not needed for the task in question.

Next, **there is no connection** between batch shape of `inputs_train_ph` and `inputs_devel_ph`, why would there be? One is independent of the other and only one is used at a time due to `tf.cond` (which has to be provided as a value in session run, but that's beside the scope of this question).

Problematic output part, exactly this:

```
output = tf.reshape(output, shape=[5, -1, num_classes])
used = tf.expand_dims(used, 2)

output = output * used
```

Tensor shapes using your approach:

```
Output shape: (5, 480, 2)                                                                                                                          
Used initial shape: (32, 75) 
Used after expand_dims: (32, 75, 1)
```

Obviously `(5, 480, 2)` multiplied by `(32, 75, 1)` will not work, I see no possibility of this working ever, even with Tensorflow in pre-alpha version, which makes me think there are other parts of your source code making it working and who knows what else influences it to be honest.

Problem with `used` can be solved in multiple ways, but I think what you wanted is to stack `used` in another dimension and reshape afterwards (**it will not work without reshaping**):

```
output = tf.reshape(output, shape=[5, -1, num_classes])
used = tf.stack((used, used), 2)
used = tf.reshape(used, shape=(5, -1, num_classes))

output = output * used
```

Using this approach, **every batch shape** passes through network without problem.

**BTW.** I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve with `used` at the beginning either, but maybe it has your use case, IMO the intent is totally unreadable when compared to final result (columns containing zeros when all features in sequence are zero and one otherwise).

### 3. Tensorflow versions

Tested with **version 1.8** of Tensorflow (current is 1.12 and 2.0 is around the corner) and **I was able to reproduce** your problem.

**Still, output shapes crash as described above though.**

Actually, **version 1.9** already has this problem solved.

#### Why this problem exists in 1.8?

I have tried to pin-point possible reason, but I still don't know. Some ideas:

- Using `tf.layers` instead of `tf.nn`. As [planned for version
  2.0](https://medium.com/tensorflow/standardizing-on-keras-guidance-on-high-level-apis-in-tensorflow-2-0-bad2b04c819a) this module will be deprecated and due to a lot of mess in the
  framework, I assumed something might be off in this case as well. I
  have changed `conv1d` to it's `tf.keras.layers` counterpart and batch
  normalization to `tf.nn.batch_normalization`, to no avail unluckily,
  results are still the same.
- According to [1.9 release
  notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.9.0) `Prevent tf.gradients() from backpropagating through integer tensors`. Maybe this has something to do with your problem? Maybe backpropagation graph is somehow stuck in v1.8.0?
- Problems with scope `tf.variable_scope` and `tf.layers` - as expected, nothing changed after removing namespaces.

**All in all:** update your dependencies to version 1.9 or above, it solves all your problems (though **why** they occur are rather hard to grasp, as is this framework).

Actually it's above my head why such changes are between minor versions and not described more in-depth in the changelog, but maybe I'm missing something big...

#### Little off-topic

Maybe you should consider using `tf.Estimator`, `tf.keras` or another framework like PyTorch? This code is highly unreadable, hard to debug and ugly, newer practices exist and they should help you and us (if you have another problem with your neural networks and decide to ask on StackOverflow)